# Network provided date and time (Ionic 2)

Tags: ionic2

I am developing an android app in ionic 2, is there a way I can determine if the time that I am getting is network provided or if the time was set manually.[image: Please check the screenshot below]

Thanks!

Comment: This is an interesting question.  Have you verified that the time is the "manual time" when configured that way?  I find it hard to believe that is possible.

Comment: @PhilipBrack you are right, I am unable to do that.

Comment: so in other words it appears that the browser time is coming from the network regardless of that setting?

Comment: if I use new Date( ), I get the time. I would want to differentiate if the time was set manually or if the time was set by the network. Thank You

Comment: I do not know the direct answer but you can do a walk around by getting time from your server or some API and compare with time in your app

Comment: @Duannx, working on an attendance app(which works offline and syncs attendance when connected to internet), there is a possibility that the user will manipulate time take an attendance and just before sync sets network provided time. Making it impossible for me to determine if the attendance was genuine. Thanks for the suggestion.